Does Trump support sending US troops into Gaza to retrieve hostages?
Jason Miller, senior advisor to former President Donald Trump’s 2024 Presidential campaign, just said this to News Nation’s Markie Martin (at the 2:38 mark of this video):

These hostages are going to get returned, or we’re going to go and get them when President Trump is back in office.

Conservative journalist Cassandra Macdonald interpreted this as suggesting that Trump would send US troops into Gaza to rescue the hostages:

Jason Miller saying on NewsNation that Trump will send troops into Gaza to go get the hostages if they're not returned before he is elected.

My question is, apart from this statement by Miller, has Trump or his campaign indicated that Trump supports sending US troops into Gaza for hostage rescue?

Just a general note, this question only asks whether Trump supports this idea (which is a totally valid question here), not whether it is a good idea or whether this is likely to work (which would not be good questions).

It must also be noted that accepting direct external assistance of that type is not something a lot of advanced countries would casually do.  It can be construed as a certain loss of "face" and, if the rescue went badly, whichever politician signed off on it might suffer politically.  IIRC, Saudi Arabia got some help from France decades ago when hostages were taken in a mosque, but that is controversial.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Mosque_seizure#Siege  Maybe Papua New Guinea can welcome the help of Aussie special forces, but I am not sure Israel would allow itself to be "upstaged".

AFAICT he wasn't that explicit thus far. Just generalities like Israel would cease to exist if he's not elected (but Harris is). And that the [Hamas] terror would stop the day he's back in office.

After the Israeli military confirmed the deaths of US-Israeli Hersh Goldberg-Polin and five others in Gaza on Saturday, Trump took to Truth Social to criticize his political rivals, claiming that he could have secured the safety of the hostages if he were still president. [...]
“This terror would have never happened if I were President, and it will stop the day I am back in the Oval Office. America will be Strong Again, and that will make the World Safe and Secure!”

As I mentioned before here, ambiguity often works in a politician's favor.
Relatedly, US voters seem to have a split attitude to US troops defending Israel, although that poll alas didn't ask about hostage rescue specifically.

The survey by the Chicago Council on Global Affairs found that 55 percent of Americans opposed sending U.S. troops to defend Israel if its neighbors attacked it, while 41 percent supported doing so. Republicans were more supportive of such a move, with 55 percent of them saying they favored sending troops, while 35 percent of Democrats and independents said the same.


Yup.  See also Ukraine war will be over in a day!  Or we better have our hostages or you'll pay Or @ JP  Mostly it seems  it's a good opportunity to attack the Dems for not having magically solved it during this time.  You honestly can't tell what is meant from the OP's vid:  it's a short, bombastic, not very specific sentence in the midst of stuff.  At the end of the day, Trump has had fairly isolationist instincts in the past.

Also US military apparently planned a rescue OP in Gaza, but ultimately just provided intel to the IDF https://www.timesofisrael.com/report-us-army-planned-then-shelved-potential-operation-to-rescue-american-hostages/

@ItalianPhilosopher To be fair, all of those issues will be moot the day Jared gets to broke a definitive peace in the Middle East.

@SJuan76: well, if all goes according to plan, Russia will be happy eating half of Ukraine and ditch Iran. Which in any case can be nuked into eternal peace.
